# Replace a Unicode symbol

Tags: python

In Python, I am trying to replace a symbol in a string.

I have this string:

```py
a = "• HELLO  • HOW • ARE  • AYOU"
```

I want to replace the "•" by ";".

I tried that, but no modification to my string:

```py
b = a.replace("&#149;", ";")
```

I tried that as well, that works in Python:

```py
b = a.replace("•", ";")
```

but when I launched in my spark-submit, I have this error:
`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x95' in file file_test.py on line 392, but no encoding declared;`

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that you need to [declare an encoding in your source file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). You do this by including the following command at the beginning:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

(Either as the very first line, or as the second line behind the shebang declaration.)

Your first code doesn’t work because `&#149;` is a *HTML entity*. It has nothing to do with Python. In Python, instead of using a Unicode character in code, you could also use an escape sequence to encode the value of the bullet character:

```
a.replace('\u2022', ';')
```

([U+2022](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) is the Unicode code point “BULLET”.)

Comment: Perfect , thank you a lot, I tried your solution a.replace('\u2022', ';') and it s working perfectly, you saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

the ascii number of `•` is 8229 which can be found using `ord("•")`
try changing the line to `b=a.replace(chr(8226), ";")`